# set Expiry Date S3 AWS cloud front, update with s3cmd

Tags: caching, amazon-s3, metadata, cache-control, s3cmd

i have uploaded to s3 images for my website and now i want to update the Expiry Date recursively.

i have used the following command:

```
s3cmd --recursive modify --add-header="Cache-Control:max-age=31536000" s3://ccc-public/
```

but when i view the image in aws console, it shows Matadata set for Cache Control as specified, but the Expiry Date is still set to None.

i have also tried:

```
s3cmd --recursive modify --add-header="Expires: Sat, 02 Aug 2016 18:46:39 GMT" --add-header="Cache-Control:max-age=31536000" s3://ccc-public/
```

and again, this put the metadata for the Expires, but the images still don't have a Expiry Date.

how do i modify all the files so that there is an Expiry Date using s3cmd tool?

any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your command looks correct. Try removing the space after the colon:

```
--add-header="Expires:Sat, 02 Aug 2016 18:46:39 GMT"
                     ^
```